# Dynamically change the itemWidth of a flexslider

Tags: javascript, flexslider

I have a [flexSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) initialized like this:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    itemWidth: width
});
```

Is it somehow possible to dynamically change the `itemWidth` after the initialization and force a refresh so that the new value is applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally had to modify the flexslider script in order to make the `vars` property available:

```
...
slider.vars = vars;

//FlexSlider: Initialize
methods.init();
...
```

Then `vars.itemWidth` can be modified and `doMath` can be called to refresh the slider:

```
var slider = $(".flexslider").data("flexslider");
slider.vars.itemWidth = ...;
slider.doMath();
```

Comment: That code sets the itemWidth and also works with itemMargin, but how do you refresh the slider? I can't find the method 'doMath()' on flexslider's documentation.

Comment: doMath is in Flexslider V2

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's not possible. One way would be to remove the content inside your container (assuming it's `.flexslider`).

```
$('.flexslider').text("").flexslider({
    itemWidth: newWidth
});
```

The problem with this solution is that you are reinitializing the whole module which might not be necessary.

Another solution would be to edit the width of the container itself:

```
$('.flexslider').width("NEWpx")
```

And the last solution: contact the dev team and ask for a `refresh` method.

Hope this help, cheers ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The problem with the first one is that the slider gets completely cleared. Concerning the second: I don't want to change the width of the container, only the item width.

Comment: The first one should be good for you. It gets completely cleared because you need to initialise flexslider again. Can you pastbin your code plz ?